# Ubuntu 18.04 no wifi adapter

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, dell, bios

I installed Ubuntu 18.04 on my Dell Latitude 5400 and removed Windows 10.

But I get no Wi-Fi adapter in the Wi-Fi settings. When I try `lspci` it shows no network controller.

[image: lspci command result]

And when I type `lshw -C network` it shows nothing too.

The BIOS version I used is 1.3.

The fan became very niosy since I changed the BIOS to the latest version (1.7). Then I upgraded it to 1.5,  but nothing changed. So I installed the version 1.3 (without knowing the original BIOS version). I upgraded the BIOS when Windows was installed and the Wi-Fi problem was in Windows too (before I moved to Ubuntu).

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text.

Comment: It may be a SDIO device.